# Json newtonsoft : Deserialize string array from an Object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My JSON is a very long one and i am fetching only one section "parent_crumbs"  from the long JSON

```
 ...................,
 "parent_crumbs":["Platforms","New platform"],
 "promise_by":"2016-08-01",
  ....
```

The code I used to fetch value of "parent_crumbs" is

```
  JObject lp_p = JObject.Parse(response_json);
  string val= lp_p["parent_crumbs"].ToString();
```

This returns the following value

```
 "[\r\n  \"Platforms\",\"New platform\"\r\n]"
```

Now I have to do a comparison with the first value from the array as the string is available in a Dictionary as key value and if available return ID

```
        Packages = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        Packages.Add("Platforms", 10212);
        Packages.Add("New platform", 10202);
        Packages.Add("Unknown platform", 10203);
        int category=

        if(Packages.ContainsKey(val))
        {
                Packages.TryGetValue(val, out category);
        }
```

So with current code I can't do the comparison straight away due to presence of [\r\n etc.

How to  get the value as a string Array without special chars like  [\r\n .

Making Model Classes  for the JSON for deserialization is not preferred way for me. Since creating class is a big job for me as lot of properties are there in JSON and is dynamic of nature

Comment: 1. There are some online tools for creating classes from json like https://jsonutils.com 2. You only need a class with the properties you are looking for (here a single string array property)

Comment: Yes  that way is possible , but i am looking for a way to do it without model classes to make sure code looks similar in all over the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the below code

```
var input = "[\r\n  \"Platforms\",\"New platform\"\r\n]";
            var array =(JArray) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input);
            bool isEqual = array[0].Value<string>() == "Platforms";
```

Comment: exactly this is what i am looking for

Answer (score 2):

you could also convert it to array with `Linq`

```
using System.Linq;

var tmp = lp_p["parent_crumbs"].Select(x => x.ToString());
foreach (var x in tmp)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
}
```

By using `Select`, it will help you convert it to array rather than to string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DeserializeAnonymousType` method for that:

```
var myType = new 
{ 
    parent_crumbs = new []{ "" }, 
    promise_by = default(DateTime) 
};

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, myType);

int category = 0;
string key = result.parent_crumbs[0];
if(Packages.ContainsKey(key))
{
    Packages.TryGetValue(key, out category);
}
```

References: **[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mwvYly)**, **[DeserializeAnonymousType](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm)**